# How to improve in Julia the Storkey Learning Performance?

Tags: performance, julia, nested-loops, quaternions, complex-numbers

Hi community I'm new here , and also new in Julia 1.0.3. Nowadays I'm studying Storkey Learning rules in different number systems. In my first attempt coding this ideias I try this naive code:

```
    function storkey_learning_first(U)
    
    # The memories are given by the columns
    row,col = size(U)
    
    # First W matrix
    W_new = zeros(row,row)
 
    for mu=1:col
        
        W_old = copy(W_new)

        for i=1:row
            for j=i:row 
                s = 0.0
                # Putting this value in the new matrix
                s += U[i,mu]*U[j,mu]
                s -= local_field_opt(W_old,U[:,mu],i,j,row)*U[j,mu]
                s -= local_field_opt(W_old,U[:,mu],j,i,row)*U[i,mu]
                s *= 1/row    
                
                W_new[i,j] += s
                W_new[j,i]  = W_new[i,j]
                
            end  
        end
        
    end

    return W_new
end
```

which is the main function and the "local field" given by

```
function local_field_opt(W_old,U,i,j,row)

hij = 0.0

for k=1:row
    
    if k != i && k != j
    hij += W_old[i,k]*U[k]
    end
    
end
return  hij
end
```

then given a n-dimensional real-valued vector, both codes creates a matrix of dimension (n x n). For lower dimensional vectors is working. But it is really slow for higher dimensional arrays. In fact, I want to store vectors of dimension n = 8192. Also, I would like to work with lower dimensional complex-valued vectors, or quaternions but I can't do better in the real case. In a second attempt I separate the complete structure in two functions, in particular, I separate the two inner loops avoinding to call the same elements repeatedly:

```
function_inner(U,W_old,W_mu,mu,row)

# Calling one time the column
U_mu = U[:,mu]


for j=1:row
    U_j_mu = U[j,mu]
    
    for i=j:row 
        
        U_i_mu = U[i,mu]
        
        s = 0.0
        
        s += U_i_mu *U_j_mu
        s -= U_i_mu *local_field_opt(W_old,U_mu,j,i,row)
        s -= local_field_opt(W_old,U_mu,i,j,row)*U_j_mu
        s *= 1/row    

        W_mu[i,j] += s
        W_mu[j,i]  = W_mu[i,j]
    end  
end    
return W_mu 
end
```

with this I gained a few seconds. How can I improve my syntax in this particular case? and the use of complex or quaternion numbers: should that be a considerable additional burden?. Finally, until now I'm obtaining this time mark for vectors of dimension n=1352:

```
@time W = RealStorkey.storkey_learning(U,RealStorkey.first) 
349.680284 seconds (268 allocations: 1.376 GiB, 0.09% gc time)
```

Comment: Adding `@views` and `@inbounds` doubles the speed for me (at size 50). Changing the innermost loop to have `hij += ifelse((k!=i)&(k!=j), W_old[i,k]*U[k], 0.0)` also helps, as does putting `@simd` in front of that loop. (Also, upgrading to Julia 1.5 is highly recommended. It shouldn't break any code.)

Comment: Thanks! for helping me. The instructions `@views` and `@inbounds` need a specific order outside the loops?.

Comment: Yes. `@simd` only works if bounds checking is disabled, so `@simd` needs to be after `@inbounds`